# SCSS/SASS @mixin $list @each iteration issue

Tags: css, sass

Given I have a list:

```
$box-shadow-properties: -webkit-box-shadow, -moz-box-shadow, box-shadow;
```

I would like to be able to iterate through this list for a mixin:

```
@mixin box-shadow-with-inset($box-shadow-params, $inset-params) {
  @each $property in $box-shadow-properties {
    $property: $box-shadow-params, $inset-params;
  }
}
```

So that I can call this:

```
@include box-shadow-with-inset(0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
```

There are no compile errors, but it does not compile to the CSS file -- it is as though it is ignored completely. Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. Apparently, you must interpolate property names when used in conjunction with a list like this. So:

BAD:

```
$property: $box-shadow-params, $inset-params;
```

GOOD:

```
#{$property}: $box-shadow-params, $inset-params;
```